# CakePHP - Use HtmlHelper::link with URL title

Tags: php, cakephp

I want CakePHP to make a link with a title that is the full URL that the link points to.

Like this: http://example.com/users/login
Instead of this: [Login](http://example.com/users/login)

I tried using a null title:

`echo $this->Html->link(null, array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));`

and a blank title:

`echo $this->Html->link('', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));`

but neither worked.  Do I need to use a different function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didnt you try the only obvious one? Passing in an URL to the title (first param)?

```
echo $this->Html->link(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

If it needs to be the full URL, you might have to do it in two steps, though:

```
$url = $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), true);
echo $this->Html->link($url);
```

Comment: Before you edited your answer, I was about to comment that it needs to be the full URL.  I found a way to modify your answer to do it in one step: `echo $this->Html->link(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'full_base' => true));`.  Thanks mark!